# iOS not displaying SVG in <img> tag

Tags: javascript, ios, svg

I have a simple `<img>` tag with a SVG source which is not displayed at all on Chrome and Safari on iOS (iPad 3, iOS 7.1).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7scVV/3/) is a jsfiddle with it.

The SVG is also displayed incorrectly on Safari on Windows 8.1 (it is squashed on the x-axis).

I have exported this SVG from Illustrator and it was created entirely in Illustrator. I suspect there is something wrong with the SVG itself and these browsers cannot interpret that correctly, but I have no idea what it might be.

I have searched for previous cases, but usually people have problems with inline SVGs or object SVGs and none of the solutions I found apply to my case.

EDIT: Upon further investigation, I have found out that there is indeed an issue with my SVG image. [This blog post](http://blog.dholbert.org/2010/10/svg-as-image.html) has a working `<img>` with SVG source, so there's proof that it works.

Also, using an `<object>` is not acceptable, because I also need to use this image as a `background-image`, which is also officially supported on iOS (and present in the blog post as well), but does not work with my image.

So my question becomes: are there pitfalls in creating a SVG image which can cause it to not display on certain browsers?

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue. My svg was not appearing on iOS 7.x, but was working on iOS 8.x. The problem was with my svg file. When viewing the svg file in a text editor, it didn't have a width and height defined in the svg tag.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    ...
</g>
</svg>
```

After adding **width and height** attributes I was able to see my svg in my img tag.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="40px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
```

...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the testing environment anymore and I can't determine if your answer is correct or not. I believe I ended up creating the SVG with another program which probably added those details in my image.

Answer (score 2):

Try to embed your svg as object  . Also read this http://benfrain.com/attempting-to-fix-responsive-svgs-in-desktop-safari

Tested html bellow (no .js needed):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
object {
width: 100%;
display: block;
height: auto;
position: relative;
padding-top: 0;
} 
svg {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/* position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;*/
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<object data="http://monovertex.com/static/Logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
<img src="http://monovertex.com/static/Logo.svg"  width="200" height="200"/>
</object>

 </body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. For the Safari issue, in the article's case the problem is caused by responsiveness. My dimensions are fixed and the visual consequences are different from the ones in the article. As for embedding in an object, it does work, but it's not an acceptable solution, because I also need it in a `background-image`. Both `<img>` and `background-image` officially support SVG as sources in all modern browsers (including iOS browsers) and here is a working example: http://blog.dholbert.org/2010/10/svg-as-image.html.

Comment: It really works :   <div style='background-image:url(http://monovertex.com/static/Logo.svg);  width:200px; height:200px;'/></div>

Comment: It works on any browser other than the ones on iPad, which was the entire point of the question. What device have you tested it on? Here's a fiddle with all the methods: http://jsfiddle.net/7scVV/4/. Only the `<object>` works on my iPad.

Comment: Yes, indeed. So what is the problem using objects? You can 'style' trick background-image with z-index and position:  <object height="100" width="100" 
            data="http://monovertex.com/static/Logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"  style=" position:absolute; top:10; z-index:300;">
          </object>
       <object height="200" width="200" 
            data="http://monovertex.com/static/Logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"  style=" position:absolute; top:10; z-index:200;">
       </object>

Comment: Yes, I realize I can do that, but it is a rather ugly workaround for an issue that should not exist. Besides, I was using the `background-image` for its `background-size` possibilities (this is another thing besides the fixed `<img>`). With the `<object>` I'll run into the responsiveness issues that were described in that article, which means another workaround. Thank you for the help, though!

Answer (score -2):

If your doing the SVG usage due to the lack of support of SVG natively - I would consider instead using SVGKit - https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

I used it for a few demos I did on the fly and it worked great.

Comment: I believe you did not understand the question: I am trying to display the SVG image in a web page, in a browser. From what I see, SVGKit is aimed at iOS developers, to use in a Xcode project.
My issue is that iOS browsers are marked as supporting SVG in <img> tags natively and yet mine does not display.

Comment: Indeed SVGKit is geared towards developers and won't help you in this case and is then not relevant for a web page.